# Why does ErrorListPlot not work with predefined list?

Tags: plotting

I have the following list

[image: list]

and try to plot it in an `ErrorListPlot`. The result of

```
ErrorListPlot[elp, 
PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.2}, {0, 35}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

is an empty plot:

[image: empty]

With the direct usage of the values in the plot command:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{30., 5.2/Sqrt[462]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt[4]},
{27.2, 8.2/Sqrt[80]}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.2}, {0, 35}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

I get the awaited result:

[image: works]

Can anybody give me a hint, why it does not work with the list? In my application, the list is much longer and it would be very inconvenient to write the list directly into the command.

Comment: what version of _Mathematica_ are you using? I've checked on v9.0.2 and 8.0.1 and I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Does `elp == {{30., 5.2/Sqrt[462]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt[4]}, {27.2, 
   8.2/Sqrt[80]}}` return `True`?

Comment: @rcollyer I'm using Mathematica 10.0.2

Comment: @Karsten7. No, strangely enough not. It gives `{{30., 5.2/Sqrt["462"]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt["4"]}, {27.2, 8.2/Sqrt[
   "80"]}} == {{30., 0.241926}, {29.3, 1.95}, {27.2, 0.916788}}`

Comment: If I'm using a step in between with `test = {{30., 5.2/Sqrt[462]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt[4]}, {27.2, 8.2/Sqrt[80]}}` and then `ErrorListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.2}, {0, 35}}, Frame -> True,  Axes -> False]` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the reason why the plot is empty in one of your comments.

> `{{30., 5.2/Sqrt["462"]}, {29.3, 3.9/Sqrt["4"]}, {27.2, 8.2/Sqrt["80"]}}`

The arguments for the `Sqrt` functions are stings of numbers, not numbers.
You can convert these strings to numbers using [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html?q=ToExpression):

```
elp = elp /. s_String :> ToExpression[s]
```

Now

```
ErrorListPlot[elp, PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.2}, {0, 35}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

should return the expected plot.

Comment: On can use `elp // InputForm` to see if `elp` contains any string.

Comment: Okay thank you very much, with the knowledge, that the `Sqrt` uses strings I can completely understand the problem. Do I find such information in the documentation?

Comment: @Lea If the argument for Sqrt is a string, it'll not evaluate to a numerical value. Try `Sqrt[4]`, `Sqrt["4"]`, and `Sqrt["test"]`. This is part of the "everything can be represented as symbolic expression" Wolfram Language programming paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because of the square symbol. Try

```
ErrorListPlot[elp//N ,PlotRange -> {{0.9, 3.2}, {0, 35}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

Comment: No, that is not the point.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was wrong and it could help, but `elp//N` does not work in my case